# Using PHP in Jquery Variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to format what new comments look like on a Wordpress comment list, using Ajax. This is the snippet I'm working on.

The full piece can be found here: http://pastebin.com/UHnPgf4J

```
success: function(data, textStatus){
if(data=="success"){
var avatar = <?php echo get_avatar( $comment, 32 ); ?>;
var author =  <?php the_author_meta( 'user_url'); ?>;
var timestamp = <?php printf(__('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time()) ?>;
var commenttext =  jQuery('#comment').val();

jQuery('<li>'+'<div class="comment-author vcard">'+avatar+
      '<div class="comment-meta">'+author+'</div>'+
      '<div class="comment-time-stamp">'+timestamp+'</div>'+
      '<div class="comment-text">'+commenttext+'</div>'+'</li>'+).insertBefore(respond);
statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-success" >Thanks for your comment. We appreciate your response.</p>');

}
```

The only one that works is "commenttext" because it doesn't have php. The others ("avatar" "author" and "timestamp") all come back with errors in Firebug.

I tried some suggestions I found, but couldn't get any to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try quote out the `<?PHP ... ?>`

Comment: For the future: Just view source in browser after running this and see how the syntax is messed up in JS, then fix it.

Comment: is this file being processed by php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing quotes around the `<?php ... ?>` tags

Try this:

```
success: function(data, textStatus){
  if(data=="success"){
    var avatar = "<?php echo get_avatar( $comment, 32 ); ?>";
    var author =  "<?php the_author_meta( 'user_url'); ?>";
    var timestamp = "<?php printf(__('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time()) ?>";
    var commenttext =  jQuery('#comment').val();

    jQuery('<li>'+'<div class="comment-author vcard">'+avatar+
    '<div class="comment-meta">'+author+'</div>'+
    '<div class="comment-time-stamp">'+timestamp+'</div>'+
    '<div class="comment-text">'+commenttext+'</div>'+'</li>'+).insertBefore(respond);
    statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-success" >Thanks for your comment. We appreciate your response.</p>');

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

You should brace the string values with double quotes in Javascript.
Like this:

```
var author =  "<?php the_author_meta( 'user_url'); ?>";
```